# Ubuntu is not installing

Tags: dual-boot

I had windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 in my computer. Then I had to install windows again then there was no more efi boot option and now i am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 alongside again after deleting partions but i am not getting boot from cd option anymore. By the way my windows is now in bios boot mood

Comment: Pls someone try to answer me

Comment: Windows 7 cannot be installed in UEFI mode from a DVD. It must be with a USB flash drive created with the Microsoft's  official tool, Rufus or similar tools. Ubuntu as well can and should be installed with a USB flash drive. If you're unable to boot from a CD/DVD that's neither a Windows nor a Ubuntu issue. It's either the BIOS/UEFI or the user's inability to select the proper settings/options.